# Can't get wine+gallium9 to work properly on lubuntu

Tags: lubuntu, wine, gallium

I am unable to get the gallium + wine package (ppa:commendsarnex/winedri3) to work on my absolutely fresh lubuntu system (reinstalled 50 minutes ago after unsuccessfully trying to edit xorg.conf led to my monitor displaying absolutely nothing after boot, which was solvable by going to the console with alt+f1 but I didn't have anything valuable on the system so decided to reinstall as it would be quicker)
I am running Lubuntu 16.04.1 LTS; my specs are intel i5-4440, radeon r9 270x (those are the ones that could be relevant that i could think of, i could provide a full list of course)
I ran

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
```

immediately after booting for the first time and then proceeded to do the following, which in my mind would be sufficient to run the package

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oibaf/gallium-nine
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:commendsarnex/winedri3 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install wine1.9
sudo apt-get install mesa-vdpau-drivers
```

after which i run

```
winecfg
```

and the option to "Prefer native Direct3D 9" is simply not at the place it should be

commendsarnex in his ppa says the following :

> If you are on radeon and want to use DRI3, make sure oibaf's PPA is installed and add this to your xorg.conf,

```
Section "Device"
   Identifier "radeon"
   Driver "radeon"
   Option "DRI" "3"    
EndSection
```

Which I tried with my previous install (which was also fresh as of two hours ago) where i did the same process and then put these lines into xorg.conf (which didn't exist by default)
What ended up happening was, it seems, that the radeon driver stopped being used and everything was running so slowly and painfully that it was practically impossible to get anything done, which led to me further editing xorg.conf in hopes of remedying the situation using the the xorg.conf manual in which I messed up and the system couldn't didn't use my monitor anymore so I just decided to reinstall

Another issue I see is that some manual pages about installing wine+gallium specify that I have to be using the open-source driver for my video adapter and showcase this with using the "Additional drivers" tab in the "Software & updates" window where they choose the open source driver
When I open that window all I see is Unknown:Unknown with the option of using the proprietary driver ("Using Processor microcode firmware for Intel CPUs from intel-microcode (proprietary)
Which, after a quick google search, seems not to be the video adapter (duh)

Never the less, when i run

```
sudo lshw -c video
```

the results point to me using the "radeon" driver, which is the open source one, indicating that I am using the correct driver to use this feature

Full results of the above command just in case :

```
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Curacao XT [Radeon R7 370 / R9 270X/370 OEM]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master       cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=radeon latency=0
       resources: irq:29 memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f7e00000-f7e3ffff ioport:e000(size=256) memory:f7e40000-f7e5ffff
```

When searching for solutions to the problem online I came upon the following statement many times

"The option will not appear if your version of wine is not patched."

What does that mean? I did install wine from the above mentioned repository

For reference, here is what the graphics menu should look like this:

[image]

And here is what it looks like for me:

[image]